# Classified geologic maps in QGIS (3.12.2)

Tags: qgis, geology

I'm really new to QGIS and trying to understand how to import and classify a geologic map. For example, here is a map from the AZ geological survey: http://repository.azgs.az.gov/uri_gin/azgs/dlio/1737

I've downloaded the GDB for the map and I can add the polygons etc, but they are all imported as a single category. Is there some way to get QGIS to create the symbology to look like the finished PDF? Please don't tell me that I need to pick each color by hand.

Answer (score 5):

I've faced the same issue with geological maps. By far the best approach is to go back to the source and ask them to provide you with a style file (.sld or .qml format) or at least the RGB (red green blue) color definitions for each of the lithologies. You can then load this style file as described in many posts for example here: https://digimap.edina.ac.uk/webhelp/digimapgis/qgis/standard_qgis_functions/applying_style_files.htm

Picking by hand is the only option I have found if the definitions are unavailable but it is surprisingly fast to do. If you have to use this approach then symbolize your lithology in grey-scales first because this makes it easiest to see which ones are still to match.